# How to listen to mouse entered over a node while its clicked in javaFX

Tags: javafx, mouselistener, pane

in javaFX i have a Pane and inside this pane another smaller pane with mouse listener. i want to detect mouse entered even if mouse is pressed. How?? ... the smaller pane does detect mouse entered but not if mouse was pressed elsewhere on the parent pane and then entered the smaller pane.

here i've written the problem in code, though i have problem in my project, the problem is the same, so i can use the solusion. but this is the problem!

```js
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MouseTest extends Application {
 public void start(Stage primarysStage) throws Exception {
  primarysStage.setTitle("Problem");
  Pane wrapper = new FlowPane();
  wrapper.setPrefSize(400, 400);
  wrapper.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF");
  Scene scene = new Scene(wrapper, 400, 400);
  primarysStage.setScene(scene);
  Pane innerPane = new Pane();
  innerPane.setPrefSize(200, 200);
  innerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseEntered = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
    innerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
   }
  };
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseExited = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
    innerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
   }
  };
  innerPane.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEntered);
  innerPane.setOnMouseExited(mouseExited);
  wrapper.getChildren().add(innerPane);
  Label lb = new Label("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t+\n\nPress mouse here and enter the green pane:\n it does not detect!"
    + " i want it to detect mouse entered \nregardless of mouse pressed or not! HOW?");
  wrapper.getChildren().add(lb);
  primarysStage.show();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In imitation to the saying don't bring them fish, instead teach them how to fish, let me show you a trick.

Use

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> System.out.println( e));
```

to detect all mouse events and show them in the console. With this it will be obvious to you which event to catch and it will help you to solve also future problems regarding mouse events. Or any event if you use `Event.ANY`.

Comment: Thank for learning me how to fish! it's really effective! 
this `if(e.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode().equals(innerPane)){/**/}` does solve the problem, but doesnt seem right way. anyway problem solved thanks! cheers!!

Comment: You need to check the MOUSE_DRAGGED event. After all you want to catch an event that happens while the mouse button is down when it's being moved over a node. That's dragging.

Comment: sure, the way it is in javaFX now is that in case we have more than 1 innerPane in the code above, the MOUSE_DRAGGED event will be exclusive only to the node it has started to drag from, that's why i used `getIntersectedNode();` instead. i'm not sure what the right way is but it works though as an alternative, using that in 
`parentNode.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {if(eventType){/*TODO*/}}));`

Answer (score -1):

my solution is :

```
line.setOnMouseEntered(linehover);  
line.setOnMouseExited(linehover);
```

add create one **EventHandler** for the **two actions**:

```
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> linehover = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED){
            System.out.println("Exited");
        }else if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED){
            System.out.println("Entered");

        }


    }

};
```